# Замена символа во всём тексте

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Необходимо каждую из ковычек обернут в span с классом.

Например, есть текст:

```
<p>“Всем привет” сказал он.</p>
```

На выходе надо получить:

```
<p><span class="left-q">“</span>Всем привет<span class="right-q">”</span> сказал он.</p>
```

Пробовал делать вот так, но заменяет только первый найденный символ + оборачивает в span 2 раза почему-то.

```
let textBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('text_block')[0]; //Тут весь текст с параграфами хранится
textBlock.innerHTML = textBlock.innerHTML.replace('“', '<span class="left-q">“</span>');
```

Comment: Если у тебя реакт, то и делай на реакте, а не какую-то фигню.

Comment: так ведь одним map'ом делается...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let textBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('text_block')[0]; //Тут весь текст с параграфами хранится
textBlock.innerHTML = textBlock.innerHTML.replace(/“/g, '<span class="left-q">“</span>'.replace(/”/g, '<span class="right-q">”</span>');
```

```js
var str = '<p>“Всем привет” сказал он.</p><p>“Всем привет” сказал он.</p><p>“Всем привет” сказал он.</p><p>“Всем привет” сказал он.</p><p>“Всем привет” сказал он.</p><p>“Всем привет” сказал он.</p>';

console.log(str.replace(/“/g, '<span class="left-q">“</span>').replace(/”/g, '<span class="right-q">”</span>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const replacements = {
  "“": <span className="lq">“</span>,
  "”": <span className="rq">”</span>,
}

function App({ text }) {
  return (
    <p>
      {text.split(/([“”])/).map(x => replacements[x] || x)}
    </p>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App text="“Всем привет” сказал он." />,
  document.querySelector('main')
)
```

```css
main { font-size: 2em; }
.lq { color: red; }
.rq { color: lime; }
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Comment: не знал что с регулярками сплит возвращает делители,  хороший вариант если большой список символов на замену.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, не делители, а группы.

Comment: я в курсе про группы `()` в данном случае я имел в виду сами кавычки `“`

Answer (score 0):

- Используем флаг глобального (множественного) поиска `/g`
- Делим текст на 3 группы:

  1. `”` открывающая кавычка
  2. `текст в кавычках` не содержащий кавычки
  3. `”` закрывающая кавычка
- Подставляем вместо кавычек (группы 1 и 3) конструкции которые нам нужны:

  `<span class=\"left-q\">“<\/span>` и `<span class=\"right-q\">“<\/span>`
- текст вставляем через ссылку на 2-ю группу `\$2`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
// константы для лучшей читаемости кода
const leftReplace = `<span class="left-q">“</span>`
const rightReplace = `<span class="right-q">“</span>`
const pattern = new RegExp("([“])([^”]*)([”])", "g")

// получаем элемент
let textBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('text_block')[0]; 
// делаем замену
textBlock.innerHTML = textBlock.innerHTML
  .replace(pattern, `${leftReplace}\$2${rightReplace}`);
```

```css
.left-q{
  background: coral;
}
.right-q{
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="text_block">
  <p>“Всем привет” сказал он. “Всем привет” повторил он.</p>
  <p>“Всем пока” сказал он.</p>
</div>
```

*Этот скрипт будет полезен если кавычки будут одинаковыми например `"` или `'` в остальных случаях при большом количестве замен наблюдаются просадки по скорости*